# How to get previously visited url using jquery?

Tags: jquery, back-button

I have a requirement to prevent access to my site using browser back button for specific scenario. Let me explain you the scenario below:

When using mysite, user can use Browser back/forward button to go back/forward to the next URL. Now if afterwards opening a public site from the same browser window&tab, let's say http://www.google.com and the user wants to go back to mysite (e.g. http://www.example.com) by using the browser back button, my application needs to redirect the user to the login page.

I have used **document.referrer**, on load event, which is not returning any value

```
$(function () {
    checkUrl();
});

checkUrl = function () {
    var wind =  document.referrer;
    alert(wind);
}
```

Please let me know your suggestion.

Comment: No, it doesn't work like that. Referrer property will show you what site led to yours, and not the site that user visited before yours. And `back` button is definitely not a link to your site.

Answer (score 2):

`document.referrer` only works if the current page is loaded by clicking a link or redirecting on the previous page.

you should use

```
window.history.back()
```

or

```
window.history.go(-1)
```

These work like browser's back button.

Comment: what if you want the url so that you can replace the location to prevent using the back or forward buttons to re access the page??

Comment: can you help with this similar one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54271468/check-create-render-urls-from-cookie-no-login-javascript